# about the number of recommendation letters

Tags: mathematics, postdocs, recommendation-letter, germany

I submitted the required documents in order to apply for a postdoc position in Germany. In the application form they had asked for **at least** two referee's contact details. I put the details of two referees in the application. One of my referees has still not uploaded the letter in spite of my request. It seems that he is so busy. My mistake was that I just provided two referee's details. Now I just want to know whether my application will be ignored or if they will ask me to provide another referee's details. Is there any chance that they consider other materials?

Comment: Hi user40491. Did you apply to some structured postdoc program or the like? And...do we get from your statement that *one* of your referees has not yet *uploaded* their letter of reference that you know that the referees have actually been asked for a reference? The latter is certainly not universal for postdoc positions in Germany, hence my question.

Comment: Actually, I do not know what exactly you mean by "structured", but it was an open annual call from an institute. My referee has recieved an automatic email from institute for a letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, the absence of reference letters will not help your application. However, in my experience the absence of reference letters is generally not reason to not have a look at the rest of your application. If the rest of your application is sufficiently strong, some additional prodding of your referee may occur.

If your application is weak without reference letters than your chances would have been slim any way.